# setting up flutter with android studio git and flutter error

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio, path, environment-variables

**unable to use flutter & showing errors for git also**

**D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.**

**Process finished with exit code 1'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

I've already installed git, flutter and dart, Even added it to my PATH (**although I accidentally created a new path file that causes overwriting the PATH file** )

but I again added it to my path variables but still it's not working
i uninstalled and installed git again
added .../bin directories to path but still it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

**It worked I've just added system32 (C:\Windows\System32) path to my environment variables PATH and the rest of the necessary path locations
like :-**

**drive name or path\Program Files\Git\bin**

**drive name or path\Dart\bin**

**drive name or path\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe**

**drive name or path\flutter\bin**

**C:\Windows**

Comment: Please stop **bolding** everything.